# Invalid element type error with simple React component

Tags: .net, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am getting an error with the following simple React code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

export class NewFloodRequest extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Panel>
                <Panel.Body>Panel content</Panel.Body>
                <Panel.Footer>Panel footer</Panel.Footer>
            </Panel>
        );
    }
}
```

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `NewFloodRequest`.

Can someone see what the issue is here please?

[image]

**UPDATE**
Per @riwu's suggestion below, I changed the react-bootstrap version via package.json and it fixed the problem.

```
  "dependencies": {
...
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
...
  },
```

Comment: What's your `react-bootstrap` version?

Comment: The package.json shows ... "react-bootstrap@0.31.5"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade `react-bootstrap` to `0.32.1` for the new `Panel` API.

[image: Edit 71l2wzllwq]